# Local Variables in Dtrace

Tags: dtrace

How do I access variables local to a function using dtrace?

For example, in the following snippet I would like to know the value of variable x using dtrace.

```
void foo(int a){
     int x=some_fun(a);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracing local variables is impossible for kernel code because there is no mechanism to instrument arbitrary kernel instructions.  Even in user-land, tracing local variables is somewhat convoluted and so, for the specific example you give, it would make a lot more sense to trace the return value of `some_fun()` instead.

If you must trace an arbitrary local variable then you will need to determine its location (typically a register or a location in memory) at the specific point of interest.  For simple cases you may be able to do this by disassembling the function and inspecting the output.  For more complex cases it may be helpful to build the object with DWARF and then find the `DW_AT_location` attribute of the local variable's DIE.

One you find the variable's location you'll need to express it in D;  note that registers are exposed through the `uregs[]` array.  Furthermore, you'll need to describe your probe using the offset within the function since `dtrace(1)` has no way of understanding line numbers.  See the section on "User Process Tracing" in the [Oracle Solaris Dynamic
Tracing Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E53395/index.html) for more.

As an example, I wrote a trivial program containing

```
int
foo(int i)
{
    int x;
    ...
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        i += 2;
```

and built it, as an amd64 executable, with DWARF...

```
cc -m64 -g -o demo demo.c
```

...before looking for `foo()` and its definition of `x` in the output
of `dwarfdump demo`:

```
< 1><0x000000e4>    DW_TAG_subprogram
                    DW_AT_name                  "foo"
                    ...
                    DW_AT_frame_base            DW_OP_reg6



< 2><0x00000121>      DW_TAG_variable
                      DW_AT_name                  "x"
                      ... 
                      DW_AT_location              DW_OP_fbreg -24
```

`x` is described as `DW_OP_fbreg -24` but `DW_OP_fbreg` itself must be
substituted by the result of the parent function's `DW_AT_frame_base`
attribute, i.e. `DW_OP_reg6`.  DWARF uses its own architecture-agnostic
numbering for registers and the mapping to individual registers is up to
the appropriate standards body.  In this case, the [AMD64 ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) tells
us that DWARF register 6 corresponds to `%rbp`.  Thus `x` is stored at
`%rbp - 0x18`.  (For more about DWARF itself I recommend Michael Eager's
[Introduction to the DWARF Debugging Format](http://dwarfstd.org/doc/Debugging%20using%20DWARF-2012.pdf).)

Thus, if you had found that the line of source in which you're
interested is at offset 0x32 (perhaps by inspecting the DWARF
line table) then you might write a probe like:

```
pid$target:a.out:foo:32
{
    self->up = (uintptr_t)(uregs[R_RBP] - 0x18);
    self->kp = (int *)copyin(self->up, sizeof (int));
    printf("x = %d\n", *self->kp);
    self->up = 0;
    self->kp = 0;
}
```

This is what I see when I run the demo program:

```
# dtrace -q -s test.d -c /tmp/demo 
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
x = 8
x = 9
x = 10

#
```

Comment: I'd venture it's a lot easier to add dtrace probes to the source code, if possible.  See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-dtraceprobes.html and https://blogs.oracle.com/d/entry/adding_dtrace_probes_to_user